# Can't install ElementaryOS on DELL XPS 15 (9650)

Tags: linux, bios, uefi, elementary-os

I've just got a new Dell XPS 15 (9650) with Windows 10 on it, but I want to install ElementaryOS (https://elementary.io) as the only OS (so I want to remove Windows). I created a bootable USB with Rufus and set is as default boot option in the BIOS.

The screen that i get is this:

[image: Screen received]
If I choose the option "Install elementary OS" I get a new screen with the E logo and nothing else.
I've search this problem on the internet and I found out that it is related to the UEFI, so I found this article on Dell website (http://www.dell.com/support/article/it/it/itbsdt1/sln297060/xps-13-9343--how-to-install-ubuntu-developer-edition-1404-on-a-dell-pc-configured-for-the-unified-extensible-firmware-interface--uefi--bios?lang=en) that explains step by step what you need to do in order to install Ubuntu on the PC, but nothing.

I tried to remove the secure boot, to switch from "RAID on" to "AHCI" in the Sata Operation panel of the bios, uncheck "Enable Legacy Option ROMs" in the Advanced Boot Options panel, and create a new option in the boot sequence with grubx64.efi as the filename (tried also with BOOTx64.efi, but nothing).

All I get is the same screen with the E logo.

This is my current configuration (after lots of tries) of the BIOS:

> Boot Sequence:
>
> 1. *My USB key with Elementary*
> 2. *The boot option I created with "\EFI\BOOT\BOOTx64.EFI" as the file name*
> 3. Windows disk
>
> Advanced Boot Options:
>
> 1. Enable Legacy Option ROMs **unchecked**
> 2. Enable Attempt Legacy Boot **unchecked**
> 3. Enable UEFI Network Stack **checked**
>
> UEFI Boot Path Security: "Always, Except Internal HDD" (possible other values: "Always" and "Never")
>
> Sata Operation: "RAID On" (possible other values: "Disabled" and "AHCI")
>
> Secure Boot: Enabled
>   Fastboot: "Auto" (possible other values: "Minimal" and "Thorough")

My BIOS version is 1.5
I've read that you can start the OS installation with a nomodeset parameter, but it seems like it's not the proper solution.

Please, if you know, tell me what I need to change.
Thank you very much

Comment: You probably need the _Super User_ site for this - Stack Overflow is for programming questions. Good luck!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up launching the OS installation with nomodeset as a parameter. After installing it I couldn't reboot/shutdown the pc, so I edited the grub file (`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`) and changed the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` value to `nomodeset`. Now it works nicely.